# not mapped value doesn't return correct

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm coding an ASP .NET Core Web API Project and have an issue about a not mapped prop in my model

Here's my model

```
public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public SqlHierarchyId NodeId { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(200)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int ChildCount { get; set; }
    }
```

and the procedure

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[GetCategoryChild](@categoryId int)
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @CurrentNode hierarchyid  
    SELECT @CurrentNode = NodeId FROM Categories
    WHERE CategoryId = @categoryId

SELECT *
,(select count(*) as cc from Categories where NodeId.GetAncestor(1) = ht.NodeId) as ChildCount
    FROM Categories as ht
    WHERE NodeId.GetAncestor(1) = @CurrentNode
END ;
```

when I execute my procedure in SQL server returns expected result

```
NodeId    Name     CategoryId     ChildCount
------------------------------------------------
0x58      Books        19             2
0x8C    Computers      25             1
```

but when I call it in Controller,all ChildCounts are 0

```
NodeId    Name     CategoryId     ChildCount
------------------------------------------------
0x58      Books        19             0
0x8C    Computers      25             0
```

and here's my controller

```
[HttpGet, Route("getChild/{categoryId}")]
        public IEnumerable<Category> GetChild(int categoryId)
        {
            var childs = _db.Categories.
                FromSql($"GetCategoryChild {categoryId}").ToList();
            return childs;
        }
```

Comment: If your sp return that key then why you are using not mapped? I mean just remove that attribute and try again

Comment: @PrashantPimpale then it doesn't return ChildCount at all

Answer (score 0):

Build a sql command and add the categoryId variable as a sqlcommand parameter. That’s how you should be calling sprocs from application code.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `ChildCount` property from `Category` model, and create a view model `CategoryViewModel` and map result from stored procedure to this view model:

```
var param  = new SqlParameter("@categoryId", categoryId);
var result = dbContext.Database
                      .SqlQuery<CategoryViewModel>("dbo.GetCategoryChild @categoryId",param).ToList();
```

Please see this Link:
[Execute stored procedure in entity Framework Core without expecting map to dbset](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/52003432/execute-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-core-without-expecting-map-to-dbset)

Comment: You **Must Not** Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In English, And Highlight Every Second Word In Bold .....